# How to Filter in Sharepoint under "Edit View"?

Tags: sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-2013, office365api

I am trying to apply a filter under "Create View" with the "Contains" and I am unable to understand how to update multiple values in that cell.

For example in the proposed view - I want to list only items under "Project Status" column with the values as "Red" and "Amber" & "Scope Creep".

I tried the option "Show Items only when the following is true" & Under Show Items when Column "Project Status" "Contains (Not Indexed). However, I am unsure how to enter the above mentioned values here ? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use multiple filters to filter the desired items.

My test:

Column: cho

Type:choice

value:1,2,3

desired items:column contain 1,2

**default view:**
[image]
**filter setting:**

[image]

**test result:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did.. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually go this way, check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqjth.png
For column updates it depends on how that column has been defined. If a single line of text, you can update it with new values from the list. If the column is a single/multi choice, you have to manage default values from the column settings.

Comment: Thank you so very much, I used the same option. however, I mentioned as Equal to instead of contains.. I appreciate your help